# MongoDB how to update a list by adding new items?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using `mongoTemplate` to update a list by adding new items.

```
{
  id: 1233,
  items: [
  {
     object: "object1"
  },
  {
     object: "object2"
  },
  {
     object: "object3"
  }
  ]
}
```

after the update should be:

```
{
  id: 1233,
  items: [
  {
     object: "object1"
  },
  {
     object: "object2"
  },
  {
     object: "object3"
  },
  {
     object: "object4"
  }
  ]
}
```

I want to update the list of items with new one for a certain `id` value.

Comment: With `$push`. You may refer to this [sample demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SmyfqehrCqp).

Comment: The `MongoTemplate#updateFirst` method takes a `UpdateDefinition` as a parameter - the `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update` class's `push` method lets you add a new element to the array field.

Comment: Indeed one may define the update with `addToSet` but the problem with it, is that it does not add elements to the list if they already exists (by definition a list in Java should allow redundant elements)

Comment: Another way, (The one I wanted to avoid), is to call `findFirst` then get the list of Objects add the new list and update the document by overwriting the old list.